# Add extra shortcuts to the Ubuntu launcher quick keys

Tags: 11.10, unity, launcher

My problem is that the Ubuntu launcher has shortcut numbers assign to the first 10. How can i extend this to more of them, like letter or more numbers. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible.

Keep in mind you can add more shortcuts (similar to the ones in Unity) in the system settings.

Comment: hello, where can i see when this changes will be added or a kind of roadmap that includes this options. thank you.

Comment: @Marysol I don't think there is a roadmap for these options as yet, though you might be able to find blueprints on launchpad. If I find any I'll pass it on.